# Completely Uninstalling Office 2007 Trial that came with New PC in Windows 7 x 64?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

I bought a new PC which of course came with a lot crapware/trialware installed on it, one of the most offending is of course MS Office 60 day trial/Home & student version. The problem is that after uninstalling, the "MS-Office Reinstall Trial" program (i want to get rid of this offending object too) remains on my PC and when trying to install the Office 2010 beta the installers says there's still a 32bit version of office installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using revo-uninstaller, it does more than just uninstall a program, it also gets rid of all traces that program left behind like registry settings.

Comment: Great program, but only the professional version ($39.25) is x64 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off User  Account Control (under control panel, user account, change user account settings and put the slider all the way down) and then uninstall

Answer (score 0):

Must give a try to [uninstall manager](http://www.samsunsegman.com/um/) it works superb...

> Removing files from your system is a lot harder than installing them.
>   Megabytes of junk files on your hard disk waste space, slowdown your
>   system, and conflict with software. The solution to this overcrowded
>   mess is Uninstall Manager. Uninstall Manager is the program that lets
>   you safely remove unwanted software and return your system to its
>   original state.